# Why order matters when comparing 2 Date Objects?

Tags: javascript

I was using Date objects and came across something strange.
When comparing two Date objects, say `a` and `b`, `a > b` and `b < a` give different results.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s29a5/)

```
var u = Date(2014,7,5,14,00);
var k = Date(2014,7,5,13,50);
alert(" this is " + k<u);
alert(" this is " + u>k);
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You should convert that date to milliseconds to make it work correctly. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s29a5/1/)

Comment: You forgot the `new` keyword. Both `u` and `k` contain the current time, as a string. `typeof u === "string"`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski yup, another mistake. Apperantly i was half sleeping. Thanks man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a problem with operator precedence.

```
alert(" this is " + k<u)
```

is identical to

```
alert((" this is "+k) < u)
```

and not

```
alert(" this is " + (k<u))
```

as you intend.

Add the parentheses and it works.

Comment: oh god.. thanks for pointing this out. now i can go and cry somewhere dark

Comment: Why *k<u* is false and *k>u* too?

Comment: because they were strings. add the new keyword. and it will work smoothly, both of them will be true